# How to write array of elements into XLS file in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an array which holds number of elements. Now I need to create an xls file and need to write all the members of array into xls file, like one member for each cell.

```
    Dim input()={"ex1","ex2","ex3","ex4","ex5"}
```

Now I need to create examle.xls file and write above input() elements into example.xls
Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

Would a CSV file be appropriate? If it is creating a simple text file using the System.IO namespace is enough. If not then you need to use the Excel COM Interop libraries.

If you want to use Excel then you need to do something like this

```
Private Function ExcelFileCreated(ByVal filename As String, ByVal FileDate As Date) As Boolean

'Create the Excel object declaration' create a excel application 
Dim objExcel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = Nothing
'create a excel workbooks object
Dim objBooks As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
'create a workbook object
Dim objBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = Nothing
'create a excel sheets object
Dim objSheets As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets = Nothing
'create a excel sheet object
Dim objSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
'create a excel range object
Dim objRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = Nothing
'Create a new object of the Excel application object
objExcel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
'Adding a collection of Workbooks to the Excel object
objBook = CType(objExcel.Workbooks.Add(), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)
objBooks = objExcel.Workbooks
objSheet = CType(objBooks(1).Sheets.Item(1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
objSheets = objBook.Worksheets
'Adding multiple worksheets to workbook 
objSheets.Add(Count:=1)
'Summary log file sheet            
'adding first sheet
objBook = objBooks.Item(1)
objSheet = CType(objSheets.Item(1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
'Assigning the worksheet name 
objSheet.Name = "Sheet Name"

objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "ex1" 
objExcel.Cells(7, 2).Value = "ex2"
objExcel.Cells(7, 3).value = "ex4"
objExcel.Cells(7, 4).value = "ex4"
objExcel.Cells(7, 5).value = "ex5"

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objSheet)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objSheets)

    'Saving the Workbook as a normal workbook format under log location
    Try
        If System.IO.Directory.Exists("c:\Temp") = False Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\Temp")
        End If
        objBook.SaveAs(filename, _
                       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, _
                       System.Reflection.Missing.Value, _
                       System.Reflection.Missing.Value, _
                       False, _
                       False, _
                       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, _
                       False, _
                       False, _
                       System.Reflection.Missing.Value, _
                       System.Reflection.Missing.Value, _
                       System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
        objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close()
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objExcel)
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: My requirement is xls. Because My system accepts only xls. So the output for this program should be xls.

Comment: @ram all you need to do is save it as XLS. just rename file to filename.xls

Comment: If I do that, entire row is appearing in a single cell of XLS file